# How to keep the record in Kendo dataSource while Adding or Editing or Cancel?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

My requirements are following

1. when ever adding new record to Grid that time I have to Add one flag column "OperationCotext: IsAdded", and
    when ever editing new record which i added just now want keep the flag same "OperationCotext: IsAdded". 
    Suppose i clickeded edit after that I don't want to change any values in that. if I click cancel or update records disappering. 
    The reason is I'm splicing that record based on model.dirty value. But It should not go that condition. I should get model.dirty value "true".
    But I am getting false that is the reason it's deleting. Please help me to achieve this.
2. when ever Editing the existing record that means record coming from database that time I have to Add one flag column "OperationCotext: IsUpdate",
3. When ever Deleting the existing record that means record coming from database that time I have to Add one flag column "OperationCotext: IsDelete", 
   Suppose that record i added just now and i want to delete that record that time no need to set any flag. just i want to remove from dataSource.

   I hope my requirement i am briefing well. If you're not getting i will elobrate more.

   Please look at my dojo example here and requesting to you to give solution in that link only. It will help for me lot.
   DOJO LINK http://dojo.telerik.com/EmoCi

   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please stop adding the dojo tag to these questions. The dojo tag is for the Dojo Toolkit, which is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this this is some logical problems with you "operationContext".
For convinience I edit your Dojo, I think the only thing is missing is when you edit , and cancel, it saves anyaway.(I commented line)

http://dojo.telerik.com/EmoCi/4

hope this help

Comment: @Macro Palma    Actually here two cases, 
 1. First Case -  if I add new data to the Grid that time I have to add "OperationContext: IsAdded" , 
    the same time if i want to edit that record the OperationContext should remain same as it is "OperationContext: IsAdded".
 2. Second Case -  Data coming from Database that means already that data saved in DB. if I want to edit that data that time only I have to add "OperationContext: IsUpdate", 
    the same time if i want to add the new record the OperationContext is "OperationContext: IsAdded".
 -

Comment: I think now is more like you want, but this "cancel"(when edit and cancel) when add  dont have "id" and kendo cannot route values i think, ive been reeading and probably you will have to do some hack to overtake this, or you can save items in db when add.  http://dojo.telerik.com/EmoCi/7